# using string builder to locate missing items in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi guys I am trying to look for missing items using some kind of matching system. The idea is I populate my richtextbox and format as desired 
but I want to go to a directory and look for items that are in the richtextbox, but not in the directory c:\s\slimyyyy, ,So far am using string builder and it works only if the first item on the list is not in the directory but if the second or third and so forth it  will get no error message any ideas ?so far this is my code works only when the first item in the list of items in the richtextbox .I want to be able to just on button click event handler determined missing items that not in the said directory, Find below is my code so far what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
public void OutputErrorMessage(string messages)
{
    MessageBox.Show(messages, "You are missing files");
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = rchTxtContent.Text;
    var printList = new List<string>();
    string dir = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";

    if (Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        string[] pdf_specFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        if (pdf_specFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            // Declare  and instantiate new string builder
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // The flag
            bool itemFound = false;

            // foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            foreach (object line in rchTxtContent.Lines)
            {
                foreach (string file in pdf_specFiles)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    if (fileName == line.ToString())
                    {
                        itemFound = true;
                        printList.Add(Path.GetFullPath(file));
                    }
                }

                // Add the item to the list of missing items.
                if (!itemFound )
                {
                    // Append to the builder
                    // if (builder.Length == 0)
                    {
                        builder.AppendLine("[Missing Files]");
                    }
                    builder.AppendLine(line.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: look into the list type Dictionary, its like a list but the words can be the indexes, and tthe value can be the count of that word for an example

Comment: thanks Thomas checking it out now

Comment: it also has a function containsKey so then you can check if the key/word exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will find your code easier to write and maintain if you keep your methods simple. Ideally, a single method should do exactly one thing. In your example, you have a method that does several things:

- Gets files from a directory
- Gets a list of names from a text box
- Compares the lists, generating a new one

It seems it's the last part that you need the most help with, so let's focus on that. What you're trying to do boils down to starting with one list of strings (from the text box) and excluding all the members in another list of strings (the file names from the directory). And *that* is very easy to do in .NET:

```
List<string> GetMissingFiles(
    IEnumerable<string> desiredFiles, IEnumerable<string> actualFiles)
{
    return desiredFiles.Except(
        actualFiles.Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file))).ToList();
}
```

Note that even though the above method is essentially just one statement, the method name itself helps document the calling code, by describing the operation. This helps readability, and of course having the logic encapsulated in a method allows reuse.

You can then write your original method like this (still does a couple of things, but much simpler):

```
string dir = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";

if (Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    string[] pdf_specFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
    if (pdf_specFiles.Length > 0)
    {
        List<string> printList = GetMissingFiles(rchTextContent.Lines, pdf_specFiles);

        // do something with printList
    }
}
```

It's unclear from your example whether you really want to keep `printList` empty when the directory doesn't exist or it has no files. The logic seems to indicate that you want a list of missing files (hence the method name I used), but if you skip building the list when the directory is missing or empty, then you wind up with an empty list of files, even though they *all* are missing.

An alternative to the above might be:

```
string dir = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";
IEnumerable<string> pdf_specFiles = Directory.Exists(dir) ?
    Directory.GetFiles(dir) : Enumerable.Empty<string>();

List<string> printList = GetMissingFiles(rchTextContent.Lines, pdf_specFiles);

// do something with printList
```

In that example, it always exclude the list of files in the directory from the desired list of files. If the directory is missing, an empty enumeration is used, just like if the directory is present but empty. That way, the resulting `printList` object will contain all of the original files.

Finally, I will note that the Windows file systems are all case-insensitive. The above will only match if the strings are *exactly* the same, including case. You may instead prefer a case-insensitive comparison similar to what the file system uses. In that case, just pass an equality comparer to the `Except()` method:

```
List<string> GetMissingFiles(
    IEnumerable<string> desiredFiles, IEnumerable<string> actualFiles)
{
    return desiredFiles.Except(
        actualFiles.Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)),
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
}
```

If you want a string containing the text "[Missing Files]" followed by each file name on each line, that is simple as well:

```
string missingFilesText = "[Missing Files]" + Environment.NewLine +
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, printList);
```

**EDIT:**

So, looking at your comments and reviewing your original code some more, it seems to me that you could get that code to do what you want simply by moving one line: `bool itemFound = false;`

Right now, that line of code is outside the `foreach (object line in rchTxtContent.Lines)` loop, which means that the `itemFound` flag is never reset to `false` after the first item is found.

If you move that line of code to be *inside* the `foreach (object line in rchTxtContent.Lines)` loop, i.e. right at the beginning, I think you will get what you want.

The code you posted really is in need of other improvements, and IMHO you should follow the suggestions I've offered above. But if all you care about is getting some particular output, just moving that variable's declaration and initialization should do it.

Comment: Thanks Peter I want to find files that are already in the richtextbox , but checking to see if they exist in said " c:\slim\slimyyyy"    directory

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your comment, but if I do, that's exactly what my answer provides: it will compute `printList` as a list of strings which are the file names from your text box but _not_ found in the directory.

Comment: The "[Missing Files]"  is just like head I use to display all missing items after print job is done .Ideally items in rictetxbox would be in this order ==>ABC.pdf, DEF.pdf, GHI.pdf, now if ABC.pdf is not there I want to get a message right now it my code does that but only works if the first item ABC.pdf was is a missing file or one of the missing file , thats where am stuck.

Comment: @Sheldon: sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. What does "right now" mean? The code examples in my answer will give you a complete list of _all_ missing files. And why would you want a message saying that `ABC.pdf` is missing except when it actually _is_. I.e. you say "only works" when the file is missing, but what does it do when `ABC.pdf` is _not_ missing, and how is that different from what you wanted? Did you try using my suggestions to fix your code?

Comment: sorry @ Danilo I suck at English , I was just trying to say my program do work but not properly sir.

Comment: I understand English isn't your native language. But it's still important to take the time to present your question precisely. If you provide exact details, and especially if you are clear about what output you get and how that's different from what you want (note that program output doesn't depend on fluency in any human language...it is what the program emits), then even with a language barrier, you can get your point across. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sheldon: please do...in the meantime, please see my edit in case I have correctly divined what you are trying to explain. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the difference between the filenames in your RichTextBox and the files in your directory, I think you could do it in a much shorter way:

```
string directoryPath = @"C:\slim\slimyyyy";
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
    return; // error message or exception

List<string> filesInRichTextBox = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
List<string> filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Name).ToList(); // get all files (as strings) and just the filename of it (without the whole path)

List<string> result = filesInRichTextBox.Except(filesInDirectory).ToList(); // give me all the files in the RichTextBox that are not in the directory
string missingFiles = string.Format("Missing Files: {0}", string.Join(", ", result)); // which will be something like "Missing Files: abc.txt, def.txt, etc...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: stefanmitph thanks a lot ,all I am trying to do is look for files that are missing ,because before i sent them to the spooler to print if a file is missing keet tab or I can just do that first before i print i just want to determine which files rae in richtetxbox but are not in the directory.